# django app JavaScript getElementById not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I am trying to POST some data to Django App but every variable is working fine except one..

This is my form:

```
<div class="subfield">
        <span>
        Found a coupon for <b><span style="color:#d95b44;" id="Store_Name">{{ storeData.0.storeName }}</span>?</b>
        Enter the details below to share with other users
        </span>
        <form>                              
        <br>
        <label for="user">Coupon code :</label>
        <input type="text" id="coupon_Code" maxlength="100"  />
        <br>
        <label for="user">Discount :</label>
        <textarea rows="2" cols="19" minlength="15" id="coupon_Discount"></textarea>
        <br>
        <div id="buttn">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="button" style="margin:0;padding:0;" onclick="javascript:submitCoupon();">Submit Coupon</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitCoupon()
    {   
        var store_Name = document.getElementById('Store_Name').value;
        var couponCode = document.getElementById('coupon_Code').value;
        var couponDiscount = document.getElementById('coupon_Discount').value;
        var data =  {"storeName":store_Name,"couponCode":couponCode,"couponDiscount":couponDiscount,
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{ csrf_token }}'};
        alert(store_Name);
        $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
            data: data, // get the form data
            type: "POST", // GET or POST
            url: "/submit_coupon/", // the file to call
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) { // on success..
             alert("done");

            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Out of three variable `couponCode` and `couponDiscount` is working but not `store_Name`...
I have tried changing variable name,id  but nothing is working
Whenever i am trying to alert `store_Name` i am getting undefined ....
And also console is displaying no error...

Comment: My bad i was using `.value` for span ...now i tried `.innerHTML` and it is working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="subfield">

    <form>  
       <span>
        Found a coupon for <b><span style="color:#d95b44;" id="Store_Name">{{  storeData.0.storeName }}</span>?</b>
        Enter the details below to share with other users
       </span>                            
         <br>
       <label for="user">Coupon code :</label>
       <input type="text" id="coupon_Code" maxlength="100"  />
        <br>
       <label for="user">Discount :</label>
       <textarea rows="2" cols="19" minlength="15" id="coupon_Discount"></textarea>
         <br>
       <div id="buttn">&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" style="margin:0;padding:0;" onclick="javascript:submitCoupon();">Submit Coupon</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

**Store_Name's span** used in the **form** then its run properly